# How to get a histogram to demonstrate a tweedie-like distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to make a histogram that would express that a group of values follows a tweedie like distribution.  That is, the vast majority of entries have a value equal to 0, and followed by a "flat area" and then a left skewed hump. There are more than 10,000 row entries. Standard histogram makes the distribution look like a point mass at 0. What modifications to a standard histogram might help to visualize this better?

Comment: Can you make a quick reproducible example? For ease of data, use `set.seed` and whatever stoch functions (or combination of `rexp`, etc) to generate a vector that approximates the tweedie distribution; then give minimal code to create the histogram.

Comment: But off the cuff, since a sizable portion of the data mass is at zero, you may need to alter the y-axis, by either constraining its limits or by making it a log-scale, etc.

Comment: when you say constraining the limits, should I be cutting off closer to 0 or closer to the right end of the distribution?

Comment: I was thinking constraining the y-axis, not left-right.